# Hidden Features of ASP.NET MVC (and MvcContrib)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It may be too early for this question, but in keeping with the hidden features meme, I'd be interested in a list of hidden, or rather I guess underutilized, features in the ASP.NET MVC framework and MvcContrib.

Answer (score -1):

The most hidden feature of ASP.NET MVC is that features don't exist.

In other words, the framework was designed to be extended.